# Backward stability of 'standard' algorithm for cross product calculation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we want to calculate the cross product $u\times v$ for two vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ on a computer satisfying $x\circledast y=(x*y)(1+\epsilon)$, with $|\epsilon|\leq\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}$ for $*$ one of the operations $\cdot,+,-$; and $\mathrm{fl}(x)=x(1+\epsilon)$ with $|\epsilon|\leq\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}$.

A backward stable algorithm for this problem can be found as follows. Write $u=\begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then define $$f_1:[u|v]\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}\phantom{-}0\\
 -\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_3)\\
  \phantom{-}\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_2)\end{bmatrix},$$ thus applying the most straightforward cross product algorithm to $\begin{bmatrix}u_1&0&0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $v$; define $f_2,f_3$ similarly. Then using the linearity of the cross product and assigning the errors to different elements of the $3\times2$ matrix $[u|v]$ for any of the three algorithms, we obtain the backward stable algorithm $\tilde{f}=(f_1\oplus f_2)\oplus f_3$.

The idea is to try to assign the errors of $f_i$ to $u_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ only (indices modulo $3$); we look for some for some $W=[w_1|w_2]\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$, such that 
$$
\tilde{f}([u|v])=f(W):=w_1\times w_2
~~\text{ and }~~
\frac{\|[u|v]-W\|}{\|[u|v]\|}=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}).
$$ 
For example, in the second element of $f_1$, we can find $\epsilon_i$ with $|\epsilon_i|\leq\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}, i=1,2,3,$ such that $-\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_3)=u_1v_3(1+\epsilon_1)(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3)$; assign these errors to $u_1$ by taking $$w_{11}=u_1(1+\epsilon_1)(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3)=u_1(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}))$$ (this will one more time adjusted later). Similarly, in the third element of $f_3$, we can find $\epsilon_i$ with $|\epsilon_i|\leq\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}, i=4,5,6,$ such that $$\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_2)=u_1v_2(1+\epsilon_4)(1+\epsilon_5)(1+\epsilon_6);$$ 
Now we want to choose $w_{22}=\frac{(1+\epsilon_4)(1+\epsilon_5)(1+\epsilon_6)}{(1+\epsilon_1)(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3)}=v_2(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}}))$ and then $w_{11}w_{22}=\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_2)$ exactly.

We do this similarly for the other algorithms $f_1$, but when combining the algorithms we should also take account the errors assigned in the other algorithms, which does not pose any additional problems. For example, when determining $w_{11}$ in $f_1$, we should remember that in $f_2$ we determine a $\delta$ such that $w_{23}=v_3(1+\delta)$ with $\delta=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})$; in $f_1$ we should then choose $$w_{11}=u_1(1+\epsilon_1)(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_3)/(1+\delta)=u_1(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})).$$ In calculating $\tilde{f}=(f_1\oplus f_2)\oplus f_3$, we also get errors in the additions, but we just assign one $(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})$ factor to every element of our matrix; since $(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})=(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})$, this does not yield a problem and we can construct a matrix $W=[w_1|w_2]\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$, such that $\tilde{f}([u|v])=f(W):=w_1\times w_2$ and $\frac{\|[u|v]-W\|}{\|[u|v]\|}=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})$. (Here $f$ is the exact cross product mapping.)

---

This is not, however, the most straightforward algorithm: clearly more straightforward is the algorithm $$\hat{f}:[u|v]\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}\phantom{-}[\mathrm{fl}(u_2)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_3)]\ominus[\mathrm{fl}(u_3)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_2)]\\ -[\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_3)]\oplus[\mathrm{fl}(u_3)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_1)]\\ \phantom{-}[\mathrm{fl}(u_1)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_2)]\ominus[\mathrm{fl}(u_2)\otimes\mathrm{fl}(v_1)]\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, I was not able to show that this algorithm is backward stable, since I wasn't able to distribute the errors in such a way that we can conclude that for some $W=[w_1|w_2]\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$, $\hat{f}([u|v])=f(W):=w_1\times w_2$ and $\frac{\|[u|v]-W\|}{\|[u|v]\|}=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon_{\mathrm{machine}})$. (Here $f$ is the exact cross product mapping.)

My question is whether this algorithm $\hat{f}$ is backward stable. If so, do you have a proof, or a reference to one? If it's not, why so?

Comment: I would like to understand why the first algorithm is backwards stable. It seems to me that six degrees of freedom is not enough to account for nine rounding errors. Adding your analysis of the first algorithm would be a valuable edit.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thank you for your comment. I made the requested edit

Comment: I am trying to follow your reasoning. I think that you should write out the explicit formulas for the six components of the backward error. Why? While I can find the first five components, each assignment imposes a constraint on the next and when I reach the last I am out of options. It is not clear to me, if your approach avoids this kind of problem. I can assemble a nonlinear system for the backward error consisting of 6 equations for 6 unknowns. It remains to be seen if this system can be solved. Please continue your investigation into this interesting problem.

Comment: One minor simplification: you can assume that the input is exact. This removes one rounding error, see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3243702/307944) for a discussion.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks again for your comments and thinking along with me about this problem. I wrote down the formulas myself and as far as I can see my first algorithm is backward stable for just the reason I mentioned in my edit. Since my question is specifically about backward stability of the second 'more straightforward' algorithm, I do not want to include my direct formula for the first algorithm in this thread, since it includes no less than $30$ different $\epsilon_i$'s; I feel like it will distract from the rest of my question.

Comment: In particular, I did not get to any nonlinear system. I'm curious whether I'm overseeing something or not...

Comment: I agree with your decision not to add more details of the first algorithm. Sadly, I have many things that I must do this week. However, I will be returning to this problem as many good exercises can be developed from it. To combat the flood of $\epsilon$, there is one technique which you may find useful, see this [anwer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2476756/307944) for a demonstration. It is not without its dangers, but it saves you pain of naming the individual errors.

Comment: As for the nonlinear system I mentioned: Try the following. Let $w = u \times v$ and let $\hat{w}$ denote the computed value of $w$. Let $\epsilon_i$ and $\delta_i$ control the backward error on $u$ and $v$, i.e., $\bar{u}_i = u(1+\epsilon_i)$ and $\bar{v}_i = v_i(1+\delta_i)$. Can we find values of $\epsilon_i$ and $\delta_i$, such that $\bar{u} \times \bar{v} = \hat{w}$.